# cannot connect with repository on a windows server, probably I need authentication?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am trying to setup a svn server, but I cannot figure out how the client can authenticate itself.
On a Windows Server 2019 Standard I have installed TortoiseSVN, and setup svnserve as a service. This is running.

Now I am trying to make sense of the documentation on how to proceed.
So I edited `svnserve.conf` like this

```
### Uncomment the line below to use the default password file.
password-db = passwd
```

then I edited `passwd` like this (not the actual passwords and users, just to show what I edited)

```
[users]
# harry = harryssecret
# sally = sallyssecret
guido = guido123
jurgen = jurgen123
```

And I restarted the service `svnserve`

Now I think I need to tell the TortoiseSVN on the client computer to connect and authenticate. Because when I try to connect like this `http://1.1.1.1/SVN/repository` it keeps waiting for ever and ever.
How do I do that ?

If I right click on the client computer on a folder and choose `TortoiseSVN/Settings` then a form appears where I can change some settings, but I cannot find anything about authentication.
I could click on the button next to `Subversion configuration file` and that opens a configuration file, but what do I alter here and where ?

I see something about `password-stores` and some explanation just above it, but that might have just as well be in chinese. I don't understand what I need to do here ?

Can anybody explain to me in simple terms, I have all the documentation but it seems to be written for people who already know this product.

**EDIT**

I started it as a service like this

```
C:\Windows\system32>sc create svnserve binpath="\"C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svnserve.exe\" --service -r c:\SVN" displayname="Subversion Server" depend=Tcpip start=auto
[SC] CreateService SUCCESS
```

I created a repository like this

```
C:\Windows\system32>svnadmin create c:\SVN\repository
```

**EDIT**
This is how the folder on the server looks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching I found a non-official tutorial on how to do this.
On that tutorial I saw that I need to use this

```
svn://1.1.1.1/
```

instead of

```
http://1.1.1.1/SVN/repository
```

as mentioned in the official docs

Now it works